# '\b' backspace escape character returns strange character

Tags: python, escaping

I have a very strange problem:

`>>> print('asdf\b\b\bjkl;',flush=True)
asdfjkl;`

However, Stack Overflow is unable to display what appears between 'asdf' and 'jkl;'. Between them is a rectangular character, with 0008 appearing inside the rectangle.
What is the issue here? I know that the `print` function is supposed to return `ajkl;`. Is there any way to fix this?

The problem does not seem to occur in the command line.

Comment: Could not reproduce: prints `ajkl;` in my Python interpreter.

Comment: When I copied and pasted the rectangular character, it was unable to display the character on this webpage.

Comment: What terminal program are you running your Python code in? Most standard terminals know how to handle `\b` correctly.

Comment: Running within IDLE displays: asdfjkl;

Comment: I was using the IDLE. It works on the command line, though. @Chris

Comment: Sounds like you should send an IDLE bug report. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Chris Jester-Young's comment up there, I discovered that this is already [a reported bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue23220) in IDLE. If you're indeed using IDLE, you'll just have to work around it somehow, depending on what you're doing with backspaces.